# Unable to set textarea value as var

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, textarea

i'm trying to get textareas value as variables, but on console.log it happears as empty even if it is actually not empty.
Here's the code that I have:

```
 $("#enableEdit").click(function () {
            var selectedDescriptionIdentifier = "";
            var selectedFlagIdentifier = "";

            $(".editableDescription, .editableFlag").prop("disabled", false).each(function () {
                $(this).focusout(function () {
                    var requestMac = $(this).attr("data-mac");
                    var requestDescription = $(".editableDescription").val();
                    var requestFlag = $(".editableFlag").val();
                    console.log(requestMac + " - " + requestDescription + " - " + requestFlag)
                    var dataString = 'select=' + encodeURIComponent(requestMac) + '&addDescription=' + encodeURIComponent(requestDescription) + '&addFlag=' + encodeURIComponent(requestFlag);
                    if (requestMac != '' & (requestDescription != '' || requestFlag != '')) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "update_db.php",
                            data: dataString,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (html) {
                                console.debug(dataString);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return false;
                });
            })
        });
```

but on console.log here's what I have as a result:

> B8:27:EB:AF:3E:4B -  -

any ideas?

thanks a lot

Comment: Can you add your html also.

Comment: why loop with .each? you can directly replace your selector `$(this)` with `$(".editableDescription, .editableFlag").prop("disabled", false)`

Comment: @Jai Cause I have a table created with some DB values and I have to loop between all the results